Puppeteer connect to wsEndpoint with GUI (headless false)
How is it possible to connect to already created wsEndpoint showing GUI?
Try:
puppeteer.connect({
    browserWSEndpoint: `ws://127.0.0.1:${port}${wsEndpoint}`,
    headless: false
});

Or puppeteer.launch but not permit to set browserWSEndpoint and is not possible to connect to already opened session.

Sorry, I don't understand--you mean the current endpoint is headless, and you want to change it to headful after connecting remotely? If so, I'm pretty sure this isn't possible, regardless of whether you're connecting to a remote debugging port or running it entirely within one script.

Does this answer your question? Can the browser turned headless mid-execution when it was started normally, or vice-versa?
